# Is there any way to change columns datatype that should be int became a float while using read_sql from table

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `read_sql` function to pull data from a `postgresql` table. As I store that data in a dataframe, I could find that some integer `dtype` column is automatically getting converted to `float`, is there any way to prevent that while using `read_sql` functiononly

Comment: See what happens when you set `coerce_float=False` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html).  Or you could just convert to `int` after the opperation

Comment: @JakeP I tried using **coerce_float** but its not helping, ya i convert that column to int but there are multiple columns around 150 out of which 20 are having this issue.

Comment: @Dhiraj Are there `nan`s in your column ?

Comment: @IMCoins yes there are which are causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Since your column contains `NaN` values, which are floating point numbers, I don't think you can avoid this 'issue' loading from the Database without changing the query.

If you wish to change the query, you can insert a `WHERE` clause that would exclude `None` values, or check if the row contains such a column value.

What I suggest would be to use `.fillna()`, and then to cast as integers using `.astype('int')`

Edit : Just in case, your question is wrong, you are saying

> Is there any way to change columns datatype that **should be int** became a float while using read_sql from table

But since it includes `NaN`, it is not expected to be an `int`, but a `float`.